# Accelerate Azure VM start time in Azure Batch pool

Tags: azure

We are developing a service which is supposed to interact with Azure Batch and create pool of Virtual Machines (i.e."worker nodes"). The Virtual machines will be created from custom image (from a shared image gallery) with some installed applications, but based on Windows 2016/2019 base OS (Refer link for image creation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource). These VMs will be scaled from 0 to n as per requirement. The size of these VMs is currently A2V2 but may vary.

The Virtual Machine start time that we measured for these VMs is 6 Min+. Are there any tips/steps which can help in reducing the time required to start these "Worker Nodes" in Azure Pool.

I have tried using:

1. VM Ware OSOT to optimizing the Azure VM before creating Image. Though it has had slight effect (the savings are from 0 sec to 25 secs), it is not very conclusive nor very impressive.
2. I have also tried using SDelete before generalizing the VM using Sysprep. The image created after using SDelete has not shown any start time improvement.

Research online suggests that VM start time performance is an unresolved issue for Azure, refer : https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/5715040-accelerate-vm-startup-time .

Please suggest is there anything that can help improve Start time of VMs in Azure Batch pool? Also, any link/research which explains/guarantees the minimum time a Azure VM will take for stating, so that we don't spend time trying to over-optimize it unnecessarily will help too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you assume it can be fixed? Why do you assume a documented structural issue can be fixed by some magic advice on a website? This is known, documented and you learn to live with it for now, or you seek an alternative (or pay to keep nodes running). Azure Batch is optimized for larger batch scenarios. Well documented.

Comment: @TomTom I do no assume it can be fixed. I am looking for something like **this is the minimum time it will take no matter how much one optimize their VMs**. This will help me benchmark my observations of VM start time. I would prefer some official Microsoft link documenting the expected VM start time range, if there is one ( I have searched but failed to find anything good). Additionally, any tips which can help minimize start time for any generalized image will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Start-up time of batch nodes is limited by how long VM's take to start and there is not a massive amount you can do to impact that. There is no documented SLA for start-up times, but general experience says it will be somewhere between 4-8 minutes.

One area I have seen some improvement in start-up times is through the use of [ephemeral disks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/ephemeral-os-disks). If you don't need to preserve the data on the disks, then using this can shave a bit of time off start-up, however I have seen that it can increase shutdown time slightly, if that is a concern.